# Python DB multiprocessing by invoking at max n threads out of m statements

Tags: python, database, multithreading

I want my DB statements to be executed simultaneously in max n parallel database calls. I'm trying to use multiprocessing Pool. The elements of the list are DB function calls  and all are fully prepared valid SQL statements with no positional arguments. Number of statements in the list can be less than, equal to or greater than n, but only n or lesser number of DB calls should be made before completing and moving on to next set and so on.

I tried to come up with the following code but I think there may be a better approach. The n:no_of_threads is  resulting in IndexError.

```
import psycopg2
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallel_execute_db(db, statement_list, no_of_threads=10 ):
    stmt_count = len(statement_list)
    if no_of_threads >= stmt_count:
       p = Pool(processes = stmt_count)
       result = p.map( db.sqlscript(), statement_list )
    else:
        n = 0
        while n < stmt_count:
          p = Pool(processes = n )
          result = p.map( db.sqlscript(), statement_list[n:no_of_threads] )  
          n = n + no_of_threads
          db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage for `Pool` is straightforward for this use case.

```py
def parallel_execute_db(db, statement_list, no_of_threads=10 ):
    stmt_count = len(statement_list)
    with Pool(processes=min(stmt_count, no_of_threads)) as pool:
        return pool.map(db.sqlscript, statement_list)
```

With the above, you will have a pool of workers that gets created to match the size of your list of work or the number of threads (whichever is smaller).  It will return after processing all of the statements and will return an array containing the result of running `db.sqlscript()` on each of the statements.

You should keep in mind that the process of creating a pool of workers is often considered to be costly in time, so you might want to think about solutions where you create the pool one time and then reuse it over and over.

A quick comment to add: your `db.close()` seems to be in a funny place. The convention that I like to follow is that a resource (such as a DB connection) should have a body of code that you recognize as the "owner".  It creates and destroys (closes) the connection. No one else should mess with it (no inner functions, etc).